# Rails - update nested_attributes not working for one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm trying to implement nested_attributes and creating a schedule is working. But it fails upon editing without giving any errors. It works with *one-to-one* relationship but not for *one-to-many*. I'm passing the id of the schedule as it is stated in this doc: [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

I have these models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

and here's a snippet of the controller for whitelisting strong parameters:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(schedules_attributes: [ :id, :schedule_for, :content, :time_zone, :date, :time ])
end
```

And here is a sample which **I tried via rails console**:

```
article_params = {"schedules_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_for"=>"pre", "content"=>"This is a scheduled message for ETS - !!!!!!!", "time_zone"=>"American Samoa", "date"=>"2013-10-20", "time"=>"11:15 AM", "id"=>"1"}}}

article = Article.find(1)

article.update(article_params)

D, [2013-10-25T16:42:50.266517 #2296] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2013-10-25T16:42:50.267789 #2296] DEBUG -- :   Schedule Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules" WHERE "schedules"."article_id" = $1 AND "schedules"."id" IN (1)  [["article_id", 1]]
D, [2013-10-25T16:42:50.273288 #2296] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

It selected the correct schedule but it didn't do an update query and didn't have any errors. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

I am using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.

Comment: Did you whitelist the params in your controller? [Strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: Yes, but I tried this via console. I'll just edit my question to add the strong parameters.

Comment: Try to use `article.update_attributes(article_params)` instead of `update()`

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the Strong Parameters `#permit` method?

Comment: Why is your Schedules model name in plural? Try Schedule.

Comment: Can you show your form code, too, please?

Comment: @lol007 , done that but still doesn't work.

Comment: @mjnissim, edited the question. Just had a typo there.

Comment: @depa, edited my question to correct the declaration of strong parameters. I am using it but I also clarified in my question that I tried this via console and still doesn't work.

Comment: @RichPeck, [here](http://pastie.org/8439294) is the link for the form code.

Comment: Your code looks fine; the only thing I can think of is that the schedule with ID=1 already has the all of the values that you're passing to it, so Rails doesn't need to commit anything to the db

Comment: Is this solved?. If not please paste your view. Something tells me that indeed because, as @MoMo said, you're sending the ID and rails might not be liking that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems that you are not using strong parameters and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` correctly.

Can you try

model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
```

controller file

```
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:my, :attributes, :schedules: [:schedule, :whitelist])
end

@article.update_attributes!(article_params)
```

It is idiotic to me that rails would reuire both strong parameters and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to work in this way, but maybe I'm missing something.

Also try using `.update_attributes!` with a `!`, this will tell rails to raise errors, so you know whats going on.

You have `article[schedules_attributes][0][schedule_for]` in your for, I'm not 100% positive on this, but I believe that this will be sent as 
    params[:article][:schedules_attributes_0][schedule_for]

Can you try putting `article[schedule_attributes][][attribute_name]`

Comment: I edited my question to correct my declaration of strong parameters. I also tried `.update_attributes!` but it still doesn't work, neither giving any error.

Comment: Can you post the form code? I'm guessing that your problem is that the form is not even submitting the correctly named parameters. Also put puts `"\nPARAMS: #{y params}\n"` in your controller. Then you can see the parameters in your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas for you:

```
def article_params
  schedules_attributes: [ :id, :schedule_for, :content, :time_zone, :date, :time ]
end
```

Should be:

```
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(schedules_attributes: [ :id, :schedule_for, :content, :time_zone, :date, :time ])
end
```

Comment: modified my question to correct the declaration of strong parameters. But I also clarified that I tried this via rails console and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at the option `inverse_of` in documentation, that linked to your question

Use it in the models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules, inverse_of: :article

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, inverse_of: :schedules
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here has to do with how you are testing it. If you look at the documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) under "One-to-many" you will see the following example of how to use the nested association for objection creation:

```
params = { member: {
  name: 'joe', posts_attributes: [
    { title: 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { title: 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { title: '', _destroy: '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}

member = Member.create(params[:member])
```

The example you posted does not pass the `schedules_attributes` as an `Array`, but instead as a `Hash`, which does not appear to be the proper usage. Although this example is for `ActiveRecord::Base.create`, the same should apply for `ActiveRecord::Base#update_attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

refer this PRO railscasts for nested association...its great [RAILSCASTS PRO episode for nested association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Rails Console

```
 a = Article.find(1) 
 b = a.schedules.first
 article_params = {"schedules_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"schedule_for"=>"pre", "content"=>"This is a     scheduled message for ETS - !!!!!!!", "time_zone"=>"American Samoa", "date"=>"2013-10-20", "time"=>"11:15 AM", "id"=>"1"}}}

 b.update(article_params)
 b.save
```

You might also want to edit article params just to make it an easy object.